# hashes are the same: rmmod, modprobe, modinfo, modinfo, lsmod, insmod, depmod

Tags: hashsum, rkhunter

I am get this same output after checking hashes of rmmod, modprobe, modinfo, modinfo, lsmod, insmod, depmod

```
root@user:/var/log/apt# md5sum /sbin/modprobe 
150aa565f1e37e2fd200523b6b4fcedf  /sbin/modprobe
root@user:/var/log/apt# md5sum /sbin/modinfo 
150aa565f1e37e2fd200523b6b4fcedf  /sbin/modinfo
root@user:/var/log/apt# md5sum /sbin/lsmod 
150aa565f1e37e2fd200523b6b4fcedf  /sbin/lsmod
root@user:/var/log/apt# md5sum /sbin/insmod 
150aa565f1e37e2fd200523b6b4fcedf  /sbin/insmod
root@user:/var/log/apt# md5sum /sbin/depmod 
150aa565f1e37e2fd200523b6b4fcedf  /sbin/depmod
```

rkhunter log:

```
[22:41:02] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[22:41:02]          File: /bin/lsmod
[22:41:02]          Current hash: fcaa05d1888ba56f72194b80cab50de49b351354116adf1d2a578c6a3c626f44
[22:41:03]          Stored hash : 31e9e2579309d2c68a812d63710cb8257601970bb73344b5ff454d362bde1695
[22:41:03]          Current inode: 27304    Stored inode: 72
[22:41:03]          Current file modification time: 1583955426 (11-Mar-2020 20:37:06)
[22:41:03]          Stored file modification time : 1578801885 (12-Jan-2020 05:04:45)
[22:41:13]   /bin/kmod                                       [ Warning ]
[22:41:13] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[22:41:14]          File: /bin/kmod
[22:41:14]          Current hash: fcaa05d1888ba56f72194b80cab50de49b351354116adf1d2a578c6a3c626f44
[22:41:14]          Stored hash : 31e9e2579309d2c68a812d63710cb8257601970bb73344b5ff454d362bde1695
[22:41:14]          Current inode: 11350    Stored inode: 60
[22:41:14]          Current file modification time: 1583955426 (11-Mar-2020 20:37:06)
[22:41:14]          Stored file modification time : 1542059677 (12-Nov-2018 22:54:37)
[22:40:48] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[22:40:48]          File: /sbin/rmmod
[22:40:48]          Current hash: fcaa05d1888ba56f72194b80cab50de49b351354116adf1d2a578c6a3c626f44
[22:40:48]          Stored hash : 31e9e2579309d2c68a812d63710cb8257601970bb73344b5ff454d362bde1695
[22:40:48]          Current inode: 27594    Stored inode: 11327
[22:40:48]          Current file modification time: 1583955426 (11-Mar-2020 20:37:06)
[22:40:48]          Stored file modification time : 1578801890 (12-Jan-2020 05:04:50)
[22:40:46]   /sbin/modprobe                                  [ Warning ]
[22:40:46] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[22:40:46]          File: /sbin/modprobe
[22:40:46]          Current hash: fcaa05d1888ba56f72194b80cab50de49b351354116adf1d2a578c6a3c626f44
[22:40:46]          Stored hash : 31e9e2579309d2c68a812d63710cb8257601970bb73344b5ff454d362bde1695
[22:40:46]          Current inode: 27591    Stored inode: 11330
[22:40:46]          Current file modification time: 1583955426 (11-Mar-2020 20:37:06)
[22:40:46]          Stored file modification time : 1578801890 (12-Jan-2020 05:04:50)
[22:40:45]   /sbin/modinfo                                   [ Warning ]
[22:40:45] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[22:40:45]          File: /sbin/modinfo
[22:40:45]          Current hash: fcaa05d1888ba56f72194b80cab50de49b351354116adf1d2a578c6a3c626f44
[22:40:45]          Stored hash : 31e9e2579309d2c68a812d63710cb8257601970bb73344b5ff454d362bde1695
[22:40:45]          Current inode: 27589    Stored inode: 11331
[22:40:45]          Current file modification time: 1583955426 (11-Mar-2020 20:37:06)
[22:40:45]          Stored file modification time : 1578801890 (12-Jan-2020 05:04:50)
[22:40:42] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[22:40:42]          File: /sbin/insmod
[22:40:42]          Current hash: fcaa05d1888ba56f72194b80cab50de49b351354116adf1d2a578c6a3c626f44
[22:40:42]          Stored hash : 31e9e2579309d2c68a812d63710cb8257601970bb73344b5ff454d362bde1695
[22:40:42]          Current inode: 27585    Stored inode: 11334
[22:40:42]          Current file modification time: 1583955426 (11-Mar-2020 20:37:06)
[22:40:42]          Stored file modification time : 1578801890 (12-Jan-2020 05:04:50)
```

apt log:

```
root@user:/var/log/apt# cat /var/log/apt/history.log.1 | grep -n1 2020-03-11
21-
22:Start-Date: 2020-03-11  17:37:43
23-Commandline: apt upgrade -y
24-Upgrade: libsqlite3-0:amd64 (3.22.0-1ubuntu0.2, 3.22.0-1ubuntu0.3)
25:End-Date: 2020-03-11  17:37:43
26-
```

ls -l output:

```
root@user:~# ls -l /sbin/rmmod /sbin/modprobe /sbin/modinfo /sbin/modinfo /sbin/lsmod /sbin/insmod /sbin/depmod 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Mar 11 20:37 /sbin/depmod -> /bin/kmod
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Mar 11 20:37 /sbin/insmod -> /bin/kmod
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Mar 11 20:37 /sbin/lsmod -> /bin/kmod
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Mar 11 20:37 /sbin/modinfo -> /bin/kmod
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Mar 11 20:37 /sbin/modinfo -> /bin/kmod
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Mar 11 20:37 /sbin/modprobe -> /bin/kmod
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Mar 11 20:37 /sbin/rmmod -> /bin/kmod
```

my operating system:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

rkhunter log for kmod

```
root@user:~# cat /var/log/rkhunter.log | grep -n10 kmod
419:[22:41:13]   /bin/kmod                                       [ Warning ]
420-[22:41:13] Warning: The file properties have changed:
421:[22:41:14]          File: /bin/kmod
422-[22:41:14]          Current hash: fcaa05d1888ba56f72194b80cab50de49b351354116adf1d2a578c6a3c626f44
423-[22:41:14]          Stored hash : 31e9e2579309d2c68a812d63710cb8257601970bb73344b5ff454d362bde1695
424-[22:41:14]          Current inode: 11350    Stored inode: 60
425-[22:41:14]          Current file modification time: 1583955426 (11-Mar-2020 20:37:06)
426-[22:41:14]          Stored file modification time : 1542059677 (12-Nov-2018 22:54:37)
```

**QUESTIONS**

- Why i am get this results?
- Why hashes of commands are the same? I am asking this because this
  command are give different outputs.
- Does these results show that really I am hacked or possible rootkits
  are exists?

Comment: Edit question to show the output of `ls -l /sbin/modprobe /sbin/modinfo /sbin/lsmod ...`. And to tell us your operating system.

Comment: I am using Debian 10. On my system they point to `/bin/kmod`. But why did `kmod` hash charge, this is a different story.

Comment: okay i updated outputs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see this on my Ubuntu system:

```
$ ls -l /sbin/modprobe /sbin/modinfo /sbin/lsmod /sbin/insmod /sbin/depmod
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Mar 12 09:15 /sbin/depmod -> /bin/kmod
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Mar 12 09:15 /sbin/insmod -> /bin/kmod
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Mar 12 09:15 /sbin/lsmod -> /bin/kmod
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Mar 12 09:15 /sbin/modinfo -> /bin/kmod
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Mar 12 09:15 /sbin/modprobe -> /bin/kmod
$
```

The hashes are all the same because those are all symlinks to the same file. Nothing to be concerned about; that's normal for these programs. And you almost certainly don't have a rootkit. As for why you don't see the update, it's because you don't understand how `apt-get` handles file modification times. Files installed by `apt-get` get their modification time from when the package was built, not from the time you installed it. If you check your log again, you'll almost certainly see an update to `kmod`; it will just be after the day you thought it would be on.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I understand what is happening now.
`root@user:/var/log/apt# cat term.log | grep kmod
Preparing to unpack .../kmod_24-1ubuntu3.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking kmod (24-1ubuntu3.3) over (24-1ubuntu3.2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libkmod2_24-1ubuntu3.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libkmod2:amd64 (24-1ubuntu3.3) over (24-1ubuntu3.2) ...
Setting up libkmod2:amd64 (24-1ubuntu3.3) ...
Setting up kmod (24-1ubuntu3.3) ...`